# Edit commit messages in markdown mode

Tags: git, markdown-mode

I configured git so that it uses emacsclient when editing commit messages. The only problem is that these messages are edited in `fundamental-mode`. Which hook should I use to have these commit messages buffer in `markdown-mode`?

Comment: You could use `auto-mode-alist` to designate `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` as a file which should be opened with `markdown-mode`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("COMMIT_EDITMSG" . markdown-mode))` solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git uses `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` as the temporary file for the commit message. Since Emacs will be prompted to edit it by git, you can associate that file with `markdown-mode` by adding something like

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("COMMIT_EDITMSG" . markdown-mode))
```

to your init file.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the question (@DoMiNeLa10♦ already answered it perfectly), but I thought that it might be useful to point out that markdown is not the best highlighting mode for git commit messages.

There is a perfect mode for this and it is called `git-commit`, available on Melpa.

Adding `(setq global-git-commit-mode t)` to your init file will automatically open `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffers in git-commit-mode.

There are [other highlighting packages for other types of git files (.gitignore, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772196/git-commit-vim-like-syntax-highlighting-in-emacs/56411482#56411482) also on Melpa.

None of these packages require `magit` (`git-commit-mode` is actually a minor mode from which [the magit `git-commit-major-mode` is built](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/31835d1108c951c5ee2744b4ab1b0d8a9e119636/lisp/git-commit.el#L165)).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what your after, but i have not tested personally

```
(setq git-commit-major-mode 'markdown-mode)
```

Looking at the code in the link below its set with `defcustom` to allow you to override to any mode you like.

https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/31835d1108c951c5ee2744b4ab1b0d8a9e119636/lisp/git-commit.el#L165

Comment: Doesn't `git-commit-major-mode` require the use of `magit`? (which I don't use...)

Comment: yes it does, did not realize magit was not available in which case @DoMiNeLa10 solution maybe what you need.

Comment: This is a useful answer because people who _are_ using Magit are likely to land here and this is the correct answer for them/me.